# How can I normalize the capitalization of a group-by column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

On SQL Server configured as case-insensitive, `group by` can have interesting results when the `[n][var]char` column is not the first `group by` column. Essentially, it looks like whatever row it encounters "first" (where "first" is undefined in the absence of an order): wins for that grouping. For example:

```
select x.[day], x.[name], count(1) as [count]
from (
    select 1 as [day], 'a' as [name]
    union all select 1, 'A'
    union all select 2, 'A'
    union all select 2, 'a'
    ) x group by x.[day], x.[name]
```

which returns, for me:

```
day         name count
----------- ---- -----------
1           A    2
2           a    2
```

Using `min(x.[name])` has no effect, since the grouping already happened.

I can't add an `order by` *before* the `group by`, as that is illegal; and adding the `order by` *after* the `group by` just defines the output order after the grouping - it still gives `a` and `A`.

So: is there a sane way of doing this where the capitalization will at least be consistent for all the groupings? (I'll leave for another day the problem of being consistent for separate runs)

Desired output, either:

```
day         name count
----------- ---- -----------
1           A    2
2           A    2
```

or:

```
day         name count
----------- ---- -----------
1           a    2
2           a    2
```

---

Edit: **without** destroying capitalisation when it is consistent between groups. So no upper/lower. So if one of the groups consistently has the value `BcDeF`, I want the result of that row to be `BcDeF`, not `bcdef` or `BCDEF`.

Comment: What output would you like for `(1, 'A'), (2, 'a')`? for `(1, 'A'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'A')`? for `(1, 'A'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'a')`?

Comment: @AndriyM excellent question; maybe this just  isn't possible to solve at the DB layer; I guess naively I'm thinking "either all 'a' or all 'A' in the second col", but...

Comment: For completeness, I ended up "fixing" this at the call site by normalizing the returned results. The window function approach probably comes the closest to what I need, but *in my scenario* (runtime-generated reporting queries of arbitrary complexity) it would not have been practical to implemented.

Comment: @MarcGravell if the data have as in Andriy's first example, groups with different captilaztions, then it isn't possible at any layer. Not without "destroying" capitalization of some groups. Lamak's answer is working, if you want this in the DB.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ it depends; this works plenty well enough at the calling layer - it is a little arbitrary as to which version gets elected, but it is at least consistent per run, which is good enough for my purposes: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/c4385cef8121e6aa10e6cb9773ff838c

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ for a computationally cheaper version, it could literally just store the first version it sees of each case-insensitive name, and substitute in one pass; `if (seen.TryGetValue(s, out found)) { row[col] = found; } else { seen[s] = s; }` (where `seen` is a case-insensitive dictionary)

Comment: @MarcGravell you could have that case insensitive dictionary in your database too, and use it to get your results fairly fast

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use windowing functions for this. By using `ROW_NUMBER` and partitioning using a case insensitive collation, but ordering by a case sensitive one, we will choose consistently one result with the original capitalisation, but it will group them as if they are the same:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [day], [name]
                                   ORDER BY [name] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_Cs_AS),
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [day], [name])
    FROM (  select 1 as [day], 'a' as [name]
            union all select 1, 'A'
            union all select 2, 'A'
            union all select 2, 'a'
            union all select 3, 'BcDeF'
            union all select 3, 'bCdEf') X
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

It returns:

```
╔═════╦═══════╦════╦═══╗
║ day ║ name  ║ RN ║ N ║
╠═════╬═══════╬════╬═══╣
║   1 ║ A     ║  1 ║ 2 ║
║   2 ║ A     ║  1 ║ 2 ║
║   3 ║ BcDeF ║  1 ║ 2 ║
╚═════╩═══════╩════╩═══╝
```

Following @AndriyM's comment, if you want the same capitalisation over the whole result set, and not just the same day, you can use:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [day], [name]
                                   ORDER BY [name] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_Cs_AS),
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [day], [name])
    FROM (  select 1 as [day], 'a' as [name]
            union all select 1, 'A'
            union all select 2, 'A'
            union all select 2, 'a'
            union all select 3, 'BcDeF'
            union all select 3, 'bCdEf') X
)
SELECT  [day],
        MAX([name] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS) OVER (PARTITION BY [name]) [name],
        N
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `upper()` or `lower()`:

```
select x.[day], lower(x.[name]) as name, count(1) as [count]
from (
    select 1 as [day], 'a' as [name]
    union all select 1, 'A'
    union all select 2, 'A'
    union all select 2, 'a'
    ) x
group by x.[day], x.[name];
```

You are correct that SQL Server chooses a value from an indeterminate row.  `min()` and `max()` don't help, because the values are equivalent.  The simplest solution is to explicitly choose the case that you want.

Comment: Don't you need `group by x.[day], lower(x.[name])`?

Comment: I meant without destroying the capitalisation when it is consistent across groups, sorry: I should have been clearer

Answer (score 1):

Use a case insensitive collation in the `Group by`, e.g:

```
select day, name, count(*)
from tablename
group by day, name collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AS_KI_WI
```

Perhaps SQL Server has problems here? Using another dbms it executes as:

```
SQL>create table t (d int, name varchar(10));
SQL>insert into t values (1,'A');
SQL>insert into t values (2,'A');
SQL>insert into t values (2,'a');
SQL>insert into t values (3,'BcDeF');
SQL>insert into t values (3,'bCdEf');
SQL>insert into t values (4,'a');
SQL>select d, name, count(*)
SQL&from t
SQL&group by d, name collate english_1;
          d name
=========== ========== ====================
          1 A                             1
          2 A                             2
          3 BcDeF                         2
          4 a                             1

                  4 rows found
```

Where english_1 is a case insensitive collation.

As expected?

Comment: I meant without destroying the capitalisation when it is consistent across groups, sorry: I should have been clearer

Comment: I get `Invalid collation 'SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AS_KI_WI'` - but I don't see how this helps: the entire server is already case-insensitive. I can see how changing to *case sensitive* would change the result, but then I'll get a grouping per distinct value, which isn't quite what I want either :)

Comment: So you get same result for `where name = 'A'` as for `where name = 'a'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UPPER` in `GROUP BY` clause to transfer all the values to same capitalization.

Comment: I meant without destroying the capitalisation when it is consistent across groups, sorry: I should have been clearer